# visibility:hidden in Angular 2

Tags: css, angular

What's the suggested way to achieve element invisibility in angular 2 (`visibility:hidden` not showing the element but keeping it space occupied)?. It have a `[hide]` directive but it seems to be similar to a `display:none`

Comment: `opacity:0` woudl seem to be an option...no?

Answer (score 134, accepted):

You can set the `visibility` style attribute with [style binding](https://v2.angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#other-bindings):

```
<div [style.visibility]="'hidden'"></div>
<div [style.visibility]="isDivVisible ? 'visible' : 'hidden'"></div>
```

An example is shown in [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/jQVoTIpLqP6TeMVlqi6E?p=preview).

Edit:
You could make a directive to make this easier:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6sac33?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhide-element.directive.ts

Answer (score 17):

You also can use the ability of angular to dynamically inspect your property and refresh DOM with NgStyle:

`<div [ngStyle]="{'visibility':isDivVisible ? 'visible' : 'hidden'}"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

You can do ngIf if you don't want your component to be rendered in the DOM.

If you want that component to be rendered but not shown you can just set display to none based on a condition with NgClass. But be aware that this may lead to some buggy behavior try always using ngIf

Comment: I updated my question, I want the component to be invisible but I still want it space occupied.

Comment: you will need `visibility:hidden` for it to occupy space. `display:none` will make the page behave as it was never rendered.

Answer (score -8):

Try [ngShow](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow).

```
<div ng-show="myValue"></div>
```

Hide element from controller :

```
$scope.myValue = false
```

Comment: this is for AngularJS (Angular 1) . "Angular" means Angular 2 (and following versions), which are radically different. The question is specifically for Angular 2+

Comment: And ngShow is equivalent of display:none and not visibility:hidden