# Why will Angular control not hide? (Hide but keep in DOM to retain value)

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I want to be able to hide an Angular control from the HTML so I can get the value in the TypeScript

I have been through many external articles, as well as SO articles, including : [visibility:hidden in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45281776/visibilityhidden-in-angular-2)

Only difference I can tell is that they are usually doing this on regular html like div's, instead of Angular controls.

I have tried the following:

```
[style.display]="'none'"  (no)
[style.visibility]="'hidden'"
[hidden]="hideElement"
[style.display]="hideElement?'none':'inherit'">
```

For example:

```
<mat-form-field class="input-width">
       <input matInput i18n-placeholder="@@Thing_N_55" placeholder="First Name" [style.visibility]="'hidden'" formControlName="firstName" value="{{user.FirstName}}" required>
 </mat-form-field>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: `[style.visibility]="'hidden'"` works for me, what did you see in this case? probably you want to apply this condition on outer element `mat-form-field`

Comment: Why not *ngIf ?

Comment: "so I can get the value in the TypeScript", what do You mean ? Why don't You just use class & css ?

Comment: @ABOS I was just thinking this, I tried that but it still didnt work.  Rafael: I want it to always be hidden

Comment: @MsuArven My larger goal is to be able to us i18n to translate variables in the typescript. I want to do this by hiding an element (translated). grab that value in the typescript, then output it to the page in another field.       Could you go into more detail about what you're thinking with class & css

Comment: did you try `[hidden]=true`? This will render the control hidden always.

Comment: Yes, it is not working either:  <mat-form-field class="input-width" [hidden]="true">
                            <input matInput i18n-placeholder="@@Thing_N_55" placeholder="First Name" formControlName="firstName" value="{{user.FirstName}}">
                        </mat-form-field>

Comment: @RafaelLucini I am able to use ngIf and it hides, but its no where in the dom.. will I still be able to get the value from the hidden field this way?

Comment: @RafaelLucini Because OP wants the element to stay in DOM...

Comment: With i18n translation service you don't need to have 2 elements or I really don't understand, the content is dynamically translated with something like {{ myValue | translate }}.

Answer (score 1):

Try making a CSS class and enabling it on a set condition.

```
.hide-element {
 display: none;
}
```

And then in your HTML try something like.

```
<mat-form-field class="input-width">
   <input matInput i18n-placeholder="@@Thing_N_55" placeholder="First Name" 
   [class.hide-element]="true" formControlName="firstName" value=" 
   {{user.FirstName}}" required>
</mat-form-field>
```

Focus being on

```
[class.hide-element]="true"
```

where its shows true here you can have any conditional that equates to true and that should apply the CSS class to the element, and the element should also remain in the DOM as its only addition CSS being applied and no controller logic removing the element.

Comment: Thanks. I am able to hide with this, but when I try to get the value, it is null. When I get the value on a non hidden field it prints it to console.    I have: HTML  <mat-form-field class="input-width" [class.hide-element]="true">
                            <input matInput placeholder="TestField" id="testfield" formControlName="testField" value="testvalue">
                        </mat-form-field>       TS: console.log(this._prflFrm.controls["testField"].value);

Comment: if the field is hidden when will it ever have a value? if it takes a value then hides you might want to pass it to a declared variable within the class when the conditional for hiding it is met.

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure if i'm understanding correct but I now have this but still getting null:  
 TS: this._pFrm = this.fb.group(...);   console.log(this._pFrm.controls["testField"].value' this.hideElement = true;    HTML :  <mat-form-field class="input-width" [class.hide-element]="hideElement">    How can you get value from field in form, if when creating the form its automatically hidden by the css?

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine:

```
[hidden]="true"
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hidden-demo)